# Google Optimisation API throws Bad Request but request matches docs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api

I'm trying to send a request to the Google Optimisation API but it throws `fieldVilotaion` errors. I'm pretty certain it matches multiple examples in the docs, and the field specification. I also tried to change it to a Number, the result is the same, the violation just doesn't have the quotes around it.

I send this JSON:

```json
"shipments": [
  {
    "displayName": "private",
    "pickups": [
      {
        "arrivalLocation": {
          "latitude": some number,
          "longitude": some number
        },
        "tags": [
          "some strings"
        ],
        "timeWindows": [
          {
            "startTime": "2023-09-04T01:30:00.000Z",
            "endTime": "2023-09-04T03:50:00.000Z"
          }
        ],
        "duration": "10s",
        "cost": 0,
        "loadDemands": {
          "pallet_count": {
            "amount": "2"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Response is a validation error:

```json
"fieldViolations": [
{
  "field": "model.shipments[0].load_demands[0].value",
  "description": "Invalid value at 'model.shipments[0].load_demands[0].value' (type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.optimization.v1.Shipment.Load), \"2\""
},
{
  "field": "model.shipments[1].load_demands[0].value",
  "description": "Invalid value at 'model.shipments[1].load_demands[0].value' (type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.optimization.v1.Shipment.Load), \"1\""
},
{
  "field": "model.shipments[2].load_demands[0].value",
  "description": "Invalid value at 'model.shipments[2].load_demands[0].value' (type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.optimization.v1.Shipment.Load), \"1\""
}
```

Documentation:

- [`Load` object](https://cloud.google.com/optimization/docs/reference/rest/v1/Load)
- [`loadDemands`](https://cloud.google.com/optimization/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.workspaces.shipments#Shipment)
- [Complete example](https://cloud.google.com/optimization/docs/introduction/optimize_tours) with the same shape that I have.

Comment: `model.shipments[n].load_demands[0]` doesn't exist in your JSON structure at that level. It should be looking for `model.shipments[n].pickups[0].load_demands[0].value`. As well as this, `load_demands` isn't an array, so referencing the first index doesn't make sense. Are you certain your JSON structure is what it's expecting?

Comment: well spotted, yes you are right, there was a different field with the same name and was not wrapped correctly, assumptions were made!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Joe Moore says in their comment the location of the array is not the one i posted in the json. Turns out the object value in the location it is complaining about was indeed not wrapped in an array.

model.shipments[1].load_demands[0].value !== shipments[i].pickups[i].load_demands